# SQL Server 2008: Convert truncated string to DATETIME and return those within 24 hours of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server, datetime, substring, truncate

SO! I've a tricky set of data I'm working with and I've got it down to what I hope is the last part.

The goal is to return records from a 24 hour period. Column `notes` is varchar and contains the date I need to check against. I've truncated the datetime portion Notes and converted it to `ISO8601` but I cannot seem to get it to check against `>= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())`

Column data sample: `Record updated: 04/06/2009 12:00:00 AM`

My initial query attempt:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, 
    SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35) as notes_truncated,  //verify we got the complete date/time for conversion
    CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35), 126) AS convertTo_ISO8601   // convert it to recognizable datetime 
FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35), 126) >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())   // substring -> convert -> compare against today's date and return those from within 24 hours
   AND notes IS NOT NULL    // necessary parameter
   AND notes LIKE '%returnMe%';   // necessary parameter
```

errors: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

```
DECLARE @sillyString datetime;
SET @sillyString = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35), 126);

SELECT SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35) as notes_truncated,
    CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35), 126) AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601
FROM table 
WHERE @sillyString >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
    AND notes IS NOT NULL 
    AND notes LIKE '%returnMe%';
```

error: `Invalid column name 'notes'`

```
DECLARE @value varchar(20);  
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000); 
DECLARE @sillyString datetime;

SET @value = 'notes'  
SET @sillyString = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUBSTRING(@value, 15, 35), 126);

SELECT SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35) as notes_truncated,
    @sillyString AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601
FROM table
WHERE notes IS NOT NULL 
    AND notes LIKE '%returnMe%';
```

errors: UsingConvertTo_ISO8601 returns with a value of `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` so then doing modifying the `WHERE` to `WHERE @sillyString >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND notes IS NOT NULL AND notes LIKE '%returnMe%'` returns 0 records.

Your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: That is because you have at least one row in the table where that substring is not a valid datetime.

Comment: @SeanLange you are correct, I went through each record and saw that some had more text after the datetime string. Would I use a regex or something to account for this?

Comment: @bardicwarrior There is no regex in tsql. More importantly, why do you use a length of 35 for your substring? Fix that and your code should work if the format is consistent (and all rows contain a value).

Comment: I have to ask why you are checking for notes is not null and that notes is like '%somevalue%'. There is no point in checking for not null here. It doesn't hurt the performance but it sure looks silly.

Comment: @SeanLange it has since been removed, it was used as an additional check in case there were alternate spellings (which I've been warned about here).

Comment: @Smor I have to set a length as there may be additional characters following `Record updated: 04/06/2009 12:00:00 AM

Comment: Your bit about the length is a bit confusing. Of course you have to specify a length in substring but why is it 35? There are exactly zero date strings that use 35 characters to represent. I also have to ask if it is possible to fix the data so that the date is in a separate column instead of squished into notes.

Comment: What you really need to do here is provide some example data that represents the problem. We are guessing here because there is nothing concrete to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try a quick check to see if the string is not a date for any records you will be returning:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd  -- make sure the date part is in the same order as 126 (4) ISO8601

SELECT OrderNumber, 
    SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35) as notes_truncated
FROM table
WHERE ISDATE(SUBSTRING(notes, 15, 35)) = 0
  AND notes IS NOT NULL          // necessary parameter
  AND notes LIKE '%returnMe%';   // necessary parameter
```

Comment: I ran this and it returned records as is but when I tried to set the 24 hour restriction it returned 0 records.